# ReactJS browser app cannot see things in the Docker Compose network

Tags: reactjs, docker, axios

I have a ReactJS project with its own Dockerfile, exposing port 3000:3000.

I also have a PHP project with its own Dockerfile, exposing port 80:80.  The PHP app also has containers for MySQL, Redis and Nginx

For the PHP app, I have a docker-compose file that creates a network (`my-net`) for PHP, Nginx, MySQL and Redis to communicate on.  However, I now want the ReactJS (which is in a separate project) to be able to communicate with the PHP app.

I added a docker-compose file to the React project, and added it to the network from the PHP project `my-net` and declared it as `external` so that it doesn't try to create it.

This seems to work: From the ReactJS container, I can ping `app` (the name of my backend service) and it works properly.  However, from the ReactJS code, if I use something like `axios` to try and hit the backend API, it can't resolve `app` or `http://app` or any variation.  It can however access the underlying IP address if I substitute that into in `axios`.

So there seems to be some issue with the hostname resolution, and presumably this is on the `axios` / JavaScript end.  is there something I'm missing or a reason this isn't working?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When the JavaScript runs in a browser (outside of Docker) you can not use `app` because that is only available inside the Docker network (via the embedded DNS server).

To access your PHP server from outside use localhost and the exposed port (80) instead.

Comment: not sure i follow.  I'm trying to access the React app from the browser, which is internally accessing the PHP app.  But when I do that, React doesn't seem able to connect to the PHP app

Comment: Is the request coming from reactjs/browser or from something else in react container? I thought the react container is only a static file server.

Comment: ReactJS (javascript) is making requests to the PHP application.  So the flow is: I access localhost:3000 in my browser, which is the exposed port for ReactJS.  When I hit that endpoint, React makes a request to the PHP container, or at least attempts to.  This is the part thats failing.  Even though I can ping the PHP app from the ReactJS container, when I try to use axios to make the request from the Javascript code, it's unable to resolve the host

Comment: If you are not using server-side rendering or a proxy inside the react container this has nothing to do with the react container. You can access your PHP server over the exposed port on localhost:80 (Check that in the browser before, that your PHP Server is accessible). For javascript accessing an other port you have to enable CORS, but you can check the developer tools before if it is generally working.

Comment: I see, that makes more sense.  Thanks!

Comment: @djt: one of the things you might want to look at is a front-end proxy, so that you can put all your services (SPA, AJAX, WS) on one port, and then have something re-route them internally. This allows you to run them on standard ports (80, 443) for maximum reliability in production environments. You can run a proxy as another container in your Docker Compose configuration.